# PC is suspended when i am downloading a file from a php page

Tags: php, file, download, html

PC is suspended when I am downloading a file from a PHP page. Here is my code in `download.php`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['file']))
{
$file='';
switch($_GET['file'])
{
    case 1:
        $file='Firefox  13.0.rar';
        break;
    case 2:
        $file='Chrome 22.0.rar';
        break;
    case 3:
        $file='English Corner Offline Setup.rar';
        break;
    case 4:
        $file='Net framework 2.0.rar';
        break;
    case 5:
        $file='WindowsInstaller 3.1.rar';
        break; 
}
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile("download/$file");
}
?>
```

And in another page:

```
<a href="download.php?file=1">Firefox</a>
```

Comment: There is no reason why your PC should suspend. A webbrowser is not even capable of doing that.

Comment: I don't understand "PC is suspended". What is happening. Is your browser not responding? Or is it another issue?

Comment: I am sure.But my PC stops working right now when i click on the link.And i received an notice "No data received" on my browser.I have cleared spaces in the file name and i received an empty browser.But it is still that

Answer (score 2):

there is only one issue I can see is you having spaces in your file . I think this is causing problem

```
$file='Firefox  13.0.rar';
```

use `urlencode` for this instead

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.urlencode($file));
```

Comment: I have cleared spaces but it still doesn't work fine.